# Drawing doesn't work

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, drawing

I'm playing with Actionscript and I can't get any of the drawing to work. I'm pretty much taking sample code from other websites and it doesn't seem to run. I'm working in Adobe Flash Professional CS6.

I currently have a (mostly) blank .fla document with a 800x500 white space to work with. So I go into the "timeline" tab, create a new keyframe, and under "actions", I have:

```
function onLoad():void
{
    var lineDraw:Shape = new Shape();
    lineDraw.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x0000FF);
    lineDraw.graphics.moveTo(100, 100);
    lineDraw.graphics.lineTo(200, 200);
    trace("test");
}

onLoad();
```

This prints the text "test" to the output window but does not draw the line.

What am I forgetting to do, or fail to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the lineDraw shape to the stage. Otherwise, you are just drawing to a buffer.

```
    function onLoad():void
{
    var lineDraw:Shape = new Shape();
    lineDraw.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x0000FF);
    lineDraw.graphics.moveTo(100, 100);
    lineDraw.graphics.lineTo(200, 200);
    addChild(lineDraw);
    trace("test");
}
onLoad();
```

source: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Shape.html